# Why is a single Thread faster than multithreading in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading

My code was very slow, so I thought i could push it with multithreading. But it got slower when I used multithreading. It is for a convolution operation. The Matrix[] in length is about 1 to 64 and each Matrix is 28x28 big. Also the Matrix[][] kernel length is 1 to 64 in the first dimension and also in the second dimension and each kernel is 3x3 big.(Matrix.matrix is a double[][]-array)

I already tried using Executorservice, but there was the same problem.

```
public static Matrix[] convolve(Matrix[] in, Matrix[][] kernel) {

    // Defining size of output matrix
    int kr = kernel[0][0].rows - 1;
    int kc = kernel[0][0].cols - 1;

    Matrix[] out = new Matrix[kernel.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
        out[i] = new Matrix(in[0].rows - kr, in[0].cols - kc);
    }

    // Convolution operation
    for (int i = 0; i < out[0].rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < out[0].cols; j++) {

            for (int m = 0; m < kernel.length; m++) { // Size of filters
                double sum = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < kernel[m].length; n++) { // Depth of filters
                    for (int k = 0; k < kernel[m][n].rows; k++) { // Stride over
                        for (int l = 0; l < kernel[m][n].cols; l++) { // Stride over
                            sum += in[n].matrix[i + k][j + l] * kernel[m][n].matrix[k][l];
                        }
                    }
                }
                out[m].matrix[i][j] = sum;
            }

        }
    }

    return out;
}

public Matrix[] convolveWithThreads(Matrix[] in, Matrix[][] kernel) {
    // Defining size of output matrix
    int kr = kernel[0][0].rows - 1;
    int kc = kernel[0][0].cols - 1;

    Matrix[] out = new Matrix[kernel.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
        out[i] = new Matrix(in[0].rows - kr, in[0].cols - kc);
    }
    ArrayList<Thread> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    // Convolution Operation
    for (int t = 0; t < kernel.length; t++) {
        final int m = t;
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < out[0].rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < out[0].cols; j++) {

                        double sum = 0;
                        for (int n = 0; n < kernel[m].length; n++) { // Depth of filters
                            for (int k = 0; k < kernel[m][n].rows; k++) { // Stride over
                                for (int l = 0; l < kernel[m][n].cols; l++) { // Stride over
                                    sum += in[n].matrix[i + k][j + l] * kernel[m][n].matrix[k][l];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        out[m].matrix[i][j] = sum;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
        ar.add(th);
    }

    for (Thread t : ar) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

}

Without threads it can do 70000 operations in five minutes and with threads it can only do 40000 operations. (Matrix[] in length = 8 and Matrix[][] kernel length = 8 and 8)

Comment: Threads won't speed up your algorithm, it's a overhead, u have no reason to use a thread here, there is no blocking operation either which can be executed in a separate thread. Optimise your algorithm.

Comment: You start too much Thread, try to start only 8/16 Thread and split the input into it equally.

Comment: @user1653941 A thread does not have to call blocking system calls in order to be useful. A very large computation (e.g., an image convolution) often can be speeded up by using several threads, each running on a different CPU. But, it has to be done carefully to ensure that the threads do not compete with each other any more than is necessary to access the main memory.

Comment: @Avitan, I don't have eoungh experience with implementing parallel algorithms to write a proper answer, but you might want to Google for "false sharing" and "cache line."

Comment: @Solomon Slow, agree, but in the general context, not all problems can have its solution executed parallely, the point is  there has to be something meanigful for the threads to execute to speed things up and cutdown the overall execution time.

Comment: I'd start off by making sure that each version is performing exactly the same algorithm. The loops are in a different order, though it doesn't look like that swap should matter. Put the code into small methods (the bytecode->machine code compiler will happily inline methods, but may choke on long ones). Do the common subexpression elimination "by hand" and use only local variables (not through the closure). Start on just two threads.

Comment: You're creating and starting threads yourself, that's very slow. You need to use a threadpool using an ExecutorService implementation. You claim that it didn't help. It should at least be much faster than what you posted above. Post your code that uses ExecutorService instead if you want real help.

Comment: @user1653941 That makes no sense. If you have multiple CPU's (like everyone has, nowadays, then you **should** use threads if your code is CPU bound)

Comment: it might not yield good results for problems of small size, the thread overhead might surpass the parallel task execution advantage, and the difference might not be measurable. Yes for big problems, subdividing to individual tasks of manageable size and using the executor service to manage threads is worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning a thread and running the thread has its own overhead and consume the resources. So it will slow down your program that otherwise gets executed in a single thread.

For eg: If your program was slow because of a blocking operation,then using a thread would have cut down overall execution time.

Note: Use executorservice- with fixed thread pools and schedule the worker tasks, and dont create the threads inside the loop thread creation has its own overhead, it will be slow.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention that the in-matrix is 28x28 big and there are 8 of them, also there are 64 3x3 kernel-matrix. Shouldn't it be faster if I use 8 threads to compute them parallel?

Comment: It depends whether the execution environment has multiple CPU cores- and then the portions or dimensions of matrix are computed parallely.

Comment: In your convolvewiththreads method, you are executing the rowwise and colwise iteration of in matrix , kernel.length times. Move the thread creation inside the rowwise and colwise iteration. Also , you will need to make double sum atomic.

Comment: It is slower, if I switch the loops. You have to create 784 times 8 threads and thats slower than creating 8 threads looping 784 times. And thanks, I found a mistake in my code, the double sum in normal convolve function should be in the for(int  m = 0) loop

Comment: Use executorservice- with fixed thread poolsand schedule the worker tasks, and dont create the threads inside the loop thats why its slower.